# Can't install amdgpu driver

Tags: drivers, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I'm I've been trying to install amdgpu (AMD graphics drivers), I managed to install it once then I was unable to login, I had to uninstall it. Now, again I'm trying to install it; this time I get the following error:-

```
user@Chris:~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-18.20-606296$ sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install –y
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [814 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [814 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:6 http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:10 http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                     
Package: *amdgpu*
Pin: release o=AMD
Pin: version *-606296
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: *amdgpu*:i386
Pin: release o=AMD
Pin: version *-606296
Pin-Priority: 1000

E: Invalid operation –y
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be following these instructions: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx.

That command contains a *subtle* typo (a unicode en-dash instead of a hyphen) which will affect anyone who copy/pastes it.  Copy/paste the corrected command below:

```
sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

I have reported the issue to them.